# Nothing happens when i press the ASP.NET Configuration button in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I recently installed Visual Studio 2010 and it works fine except one thing:
When I press the ASP.NET Configuration button above the solution explorer, nothing happens.

I'm running Windows 7 32-bit and have setup a server using aspnet_regsql.exe, which is correctly configured in web.config with LocalSqlServer connectionstring and in the membership and role provider.

I hope you can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a quick check I looked on the Microsoft Connect for Visual Studio site. It seems this is not a previously reported problem, so I guess it would be a local problem for you, as other people have been able to open the wizard: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/102477/asp-net-configuration-wizard-opens-in-existing-browser-window

Comment: Strange. I opened the exact same project in Visual Studio 2008, which was able to open ASP.NET configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this is because the path to your application contains non-standard characters (such as a space). Open your browser and point it to this URL to get the asp.net configuration page.

```
http://localhost:<port>/asp.netwebadminfiles/default.aspx?applicationPhysicalPath=<path to webapp>&applicationUrl=<application url>
```

Remember to escape non-standard URL characters (ie. a space is `%20`).

The "application url" by default is `/`